# How do I Clear the Contents of a TImage Prior to an OnPaint message?

Tags: c++, c++builder

My application during the initial startup draws graphical information to the `TImage` object called `Image1` located on `Form1`. After a user selects a different option from a combo box using the `OnChange` event message, I need to clear `Image1` and redraw the information using different contents. The problem is that `Image1` retains the original content and simply adds the new content to it.

I've looked for a method that would clear/erase the `Image1` contents but haven't been able to locate it. I've also tried to call the `Invalidate()` function prior to the redraw sequence without success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

This is an example of the initial output from the app.

[image]

This is an example of the output after selecting a different option from the combo box. The yellow highlights the original content and you can see the redraw has been done because the circles have a line drawn through them.

[image]

Here is a smaller example although its not drawing the rectangle or circle when selected from the combo box:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

TColor oldColor;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
{
    oldColor=Image1->Canvas->Brush->Color;
    Image1->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid;
    Image1->Canvas->Brush->Color=clWhite;
    Image1->Canvas->FillRect(Rect(0,0,241,145));
    Image1->Canvas->Brush->Color=oldColor;
    DrawBoxes();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::DrawBoxes(void)
{
    Image1->Canvas->Rectangle(10,10,30,30);
    Image1->Canvas->Rectangle(50,50,70,70);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::cbDropDownSelect(TObject *Sender)
{
    char str[10];

    if (ComboBox1->Text == "1") {
        DrawRectangle();
    }
    else {
        DrawCircle();
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::DrawRectangle(void)
{
    Image1->Canvas->Rectangle(20,20,200,130);
    Image1->Invalidate();
}

void __fastcall TForm1::DrawCircle(void)
{
    Image1->Canvas->Ellipse(50,50,100,100);
    Image1->Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Wow , this is a LOT of code to look through. Please reduce it to a [mcve]. This code is a bad mix of C and C++, and full of bad practices. But anyway, your drawing logic needs reworking. Do not call the Form's `OnPaint` handler directly. You are doing so much manual drawing, you are better off switching to `TPaintBox` with its own `OnPaint` event and `Canvas`. You are not using `TImage` the way it's meant to be used.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I was able to solve the issue by using the TPaintBox and not calling the OnPaint function directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assign `NULL` to the `TImage::Picture` property to release any graphic it is currently holding.

Or, if it is holding a `TBitmap`, you can use the `TImage::Canvas->FillRect()` method to fill it with your desired background color before drawing on it.

Or, you can simply draw your updated content onto a temporary `TBitmap` first, and then `Assign()` that to the `TImage::Picture`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried the first option and it did not work (its in the code) posted above. Since I'm not using the TBitmap I don't think the other options will work.

Comment: @Skypilot65 I would just try `FillRect()` as suggested, with the proper brush and area.

Comment: @MatG I added the following lines in place of the Image1->Picture=NULL;  Image1->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid; and Image1->Canvas->Brush->Color=clWhite; and Image1->Canvas->FilLRect(Rect(0,0,745,385)); without success. I'm getting the same results.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, let me go back to the drawing board an see if I can figure out the TPaintBox and how it works. Yes there are bad practices in this code set. I am working on a smaller version of the code set to post.